# Data.Text operations issuing error due to type incompatibility on Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write an abbreviate function like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-deferred-type-errors #-}

module Acronym (abbreviate) where

import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

abbreviate :: Text -> Text
abbreviate xs = T.concat (map T.head (T.splitOn " " xs))
```

but I am getting this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘Text’
      Expected type: [Text]
        Actual type: [Char]
    • In the first argument of ‘T.concat’, namely
        ‘(map T.head (T.splitOn " " xs))’
      In the expression: T.concat (map T.head (T.splitOn " " xs))
      In an equation for ‘abbreviate’:
          abbreviate xs = T.concat (map T.head (T.splitOn " " xs))
   |        
10 | abbreviate xs = T.concat (map T.head (T.splitOn " " xs))
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any help on resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Recommendation: use `T.take 1` instead of `T.head`. This way a trailing space or double space won't crash your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T.head` has type `Text -> Char`, so the result of `map T.head (T.splitOn " " xs)` is a value of type `[Char]`. `T.concat` has type `[Text] -> Text`, so they are not compatible. Use `T.pack` instead which has the correct type `[Char] -> Text` (or `String -> Text` which is the same thing).

Comment: thanks! I was also hoping to apply `toUpper` and was wondering how I might be able to slip that in.

Comment: You can do that at the end `T.toUpper (T.pack (map T.head (T.splitOn " " xs)))`.